# Having problem in in url

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I am having a little problem, it maybe easy but i really don't know how do I get that?
    right now my site runs on http://www.example.com this url, but i need to run that on http://example.com also.

can some body tell me here that how can i do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is probably a web hosting issue, not a redirection issue. Better asked on http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Comment: Are the DNS A records same for both? Is your webserver set to {serve the same content for both} or {serve one, redirect to it from the other}?

Comment: @Piskvor, actually I'm having unmanaged server, so having control panel differently, so bit of confuse that if redirection is the issue , where can i do that from?

Comment: That's not a setting in some control panel, that's a description of behavior. In other words, you need the DNS lookup for example.com to return the same IP address as lookup for www.example.com; next, you need to set your webserver (Apache, IIS, what-have-you) to serve content for both www.example.com and example.com. How to do that step depends on your server make and version.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this (pretty old) [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/02/url-rewriting-to-prevent-duplicate-urls.html) by Jeff might help you